# docker SDK from python starting a container

Tags: python, docker

I'm trying to execute the relevant docker command `docker-compose up -d` from python script, but can't find a way to do it.
I'm using Docker SDK from python 2.0.

Here is an example:

```
import docker
client = docker.from_env()

print client.containers.list()

container = client.containers.run("mysql:latest", detach=True)

container.start()

print client.containers.list()
```

and after that when i write in the terminal `docker ps` i get zero started containers.

Answer (score 0):

`docker ps` only shows running containers, use `docker ps -a` to see all of them (including exited containers). Your container has exited, because it requires some environment variables to be set. You can see this from the exited container logs.

```
docker logs $(docker ps -n 1 -q)
```